# How to retrieve child snapshots in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to create a `childSnapshot` in firebase using `for child in snapShot.children` I know back then I used to be able to make it work, Im not sure if this was change in the new update

-old way that used to work

```
 for child in snapshot.children {                   
                        let firUserId = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "userId").value! as! String
                    let receivePostSnapshot = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "receivePost")
    }
```

my current code does not work

```
func displayAvailaibleHelprOnMap(){
let refUrl = "frontEnd/users"
    let childRef = Ref.childRef(refUrl: refUrl)//.child("users")
    childRef.observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
    let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

     for child in snapshot.children{
// I want to use child snapshot here
//let childDict = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "receivePost")
 }

}
```

Comment: If *my current code does work*, What exactly is your question or error?

Comment: @Dravidian it should say not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
  var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
  ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
  ref.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                for snap in snapshots
                {
                    let firUserId = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "userId").value! as! String
                    let receivePostSnapshot = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "receivePost")  
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let mRef = mRestCallObj.getReferenceFirebase()
                          mRef!.child("users").queryOrderedByChild("receivePost").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let userName = snapshot.value!["receivePost"] as? String
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users + infomation").child(userid).child("cats")`
ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock : {(snapShot) in

        if let val = snapShot.value as? Int {print(snapShot)}
```